# Why haven't Sorted JLists been made part of the standard Swing library yet?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, sorting

"[Creating a Sorted JList Component](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/sorted_jlist/)" says,

> Version 6 of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE, formerly
>   referred to as J2SE) will add sorting and filtering abilities to the
>   `javax.swing.JTable` class.* The Java Foundation Classes/Swing
>   (JFC/Swing) engineering team has added a `TableRowSorter` class to Java
>   SE 6 to handle sorting and filtering. This class behaves like a
>   decorator in that it represents the underlying table model and adds
>   sorting to it at runtime. You create a `TableRowSorter` object by
>   providing the original table model in the constructor. Then you call
>   the table's `setRowSorter` method. Thereafter, the `JTable` object will
>   use the `TableRowSorter` object to get a sorted representation of the
>   base model. Unfortunately, this same feature is not yet available for
>   the `JList` class, nor will it be available in the next release. But we
>   can borrow the decorator idea to create a `SortedListModel` class that
>   adds sorting abilities to any `ListModel` object. Note: The demo
>   application and code in this article apply to all versions of the JDK
>   through version 6.

Has anyone heard if they're planning on including it in Java 7, 8, or 9? Because this is how it's make me feel:

> Lists are appropriate UI components for many applications, but an
>   **unsorted list has limited usefulness**.

(emphasis by me)

Comment: Isn't it along the lines "Swing is long dead, though people are constantly using it"?

Comment: @Anonymous, I hope not...Swing is still widely supported, although looks like JavaFX will dethrone it.

Comment: @Крысa JList is very simple JComponent with one dimension, designated only for Lenght, there no requirement for somehow complicated Comparator in other hands required basic stuff from programing knowledges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can't say anything to the why - if you need a sortable list view, use JXList (of the SwingX project): it supports sorting/filtering along the exact same lines as J/X/Table does.